# how to return rownum column value with HQL? (using oracle db)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle10g, hql

I have a complicated HQL query.

I would like to access the Oracle specific **rownum** column value as part of my returned results.  How do I write my query (and/or change my hbm.xml) to support this?

What I have tried so far does not work:

modifying my hbm.xml

```
<property name="rownum" type="int" update="false" insert="false" generated="never"/>
```

and a query such as:

```
"select dog.rownum from Dog as dog where ..."
```

But I get *java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification*

I suspect I might need to mix some sql with my complex hql query...  suggestions welcome.  Thanks.

---

Some background:

- http://ronfrancis.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/dont-forget-an-order-by-for-pagination-queries/
- hibernate uses oracle's rownum 'under the hood' to paginate results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ROWNUM doesn't belong to any table, so your query should be:

```
"select rownum from Dog as dog where ..."
```

For example:

```
SQL> select emp.ename, rownum from emp;

ENAME          ROWNUM
---------- ----------
SMITH               1
ALLEN               2
WARD                3
JONES               4
MARTIN              5
BLAKE               6
CLARK               7
SCOTT               8
KING                9
TURNER             10
```

Comment: for such a statement what would hibernate return in java ? a List<Map<String,Long>> ?

Comment: @miss_R Sorry I don't know

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it in the mapping, you might try to define it as a formula instead of a column. Hibernate may not pre-pend the table name if it doesn't recognize it as a column.